# c++ Class user select use FIFO or LIFO

Tags: c++

I need a class that user select work with FIFO or LIFO, the combination of queue class and stack class.

how The combination of these two classes that user select works with Which one

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're asking for [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). It supports constant time insertion and removal from both ends. The available member functions include `push_back`, `pop_back`, `push_front` and `pop_front`.